# How can I automatically disable WiFi when I connect to an Ethernet network?

Tags: macos, wifi, ethernet

I would like my WiFi to automatically disconnect when I plug an Ethernet cable into my Mac. How would I go about this?

Comment: Could you put some more effort into describing "Cable" and how you have things set up? Ethernet, Cable Modem, some other cable? OS X handles multiple network interfaces without any intervention so it's not clear what you are even trying to accomplish.

Comment: Cable ethernet, i mean!

Comment: Do you want to have the entire WiFi system turn off when you connect the Ethernet cable? Also: I edited your question. Is it still correct?

Comment: The question makes a lot of sense to me: how to turn off the wifi radio when going on to ethernet. There are a lot of busy office wifi environments where it'd be beneficial.

Comment: Any way to do this on 10.9 and up?

Service order has no effect on my machine. Some operations still default to to WiFi.

Answer (score 5):

If you have somehow modified the default service ordering, you can set it again in the network tab using the gear.

This makes the Wi-Fi inactive for internet routing whenever you connect the cable. What you ask is scriptable if you know some programming, but there isn't a simple trigger to actually turn the Wi-Fi radio off at the user level of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

[This script on MacOSXHints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100927161027611) worked for me up until installing Mavericks (10.9.0) on a new Late 2013 MBP retina 15" - but it did work quite well on my previous two non-retina MBPs before that.

Note that you may need to edit the script to use your correct interface numbers (ie en1).