# Updating the Wi-Fi/Ethernet toggle script for Mavericks & new MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, macos

So I used to use [this script from MacOSXHints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100927161027611) to automatically toggle my Wi-Fi whenever I connected my OS X 10.6 and 10.8 MBPs into Ethernet or my 27" TB Display:

> Ever been annoyed to be on both wireless AND wired network at the same time, without the opportunity to automatically disable AirPort when plugging in a cable?
>
> Well this little script and launchd agent will auto-disable AirPort on active ethernet.

Since installing Mavericks on my new Late 2013 retina MBP 15, even after editing the interface names to the new system's (en5, for example) the script no longer works; I think that the old `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration` folder is no longer used or working the same in Mavs as in previous releases..

Comment: What about [using the service order](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64454/37797) to decide whether to use Wi-Fi/Ethernet?

Comment: That will decide the active interface, sure; I'm interested in revising this script to actually toggle Wi-Fi power on/off based on the state of the Ethernet interface.  Once you get used to it, it's practically barbaric to have to manually switch it again..

Comment: Yes; I had been using ControlPlane for other system toggles, but version 1.4.0 seems to be buggy on 10.9.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to a different script for the same purpose, but with a slightly different approach. It uses the same SystemConfiguration trigger, thus. The problem on Mavericks seem rather to be respawning the original script over and over by launchd. I'm successfully running it on Mavericks 10.9.3. The Script can be found here: http://www.computernetworkbasics.com/2012/12/automatically-turn-off-wireless-in-osx-including-mountain-lion/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.